# Decoding CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, utf-8, spreadsheet

df=pandas.read_csv("commaSeperated.csv")
imported csv file into pandas, but viewing the pandas.columns i got this file format

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SR8Fp.png)

Viewing the head of the file with pandas.head() i got this file output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuYuC.png)

Now my question is, is the any way i could output a proper CSV file without these characters

[This is how it looks in notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EFVc.png)
"003      ""|""   ""|""         ""|""7105926                                                                                                                                                                                                           ""|""   ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                              ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""                                                                                                         ""|""GREEN                                                                                                    ""|""         ""|""         ""|""24-APR-20""|""GH20200071398001DK                                          ""|""   ""|""   ""|""   ""|""TNMSCA12                                                    ""|""         ""|""

Comment: A csv file is a **text** file. What does it look like in a text editor like notepad++, vi or even the good old notepad if using Windows?

Comment: just upload how it looks in notepad++

Comment: Please stop posting images and post data as copyable text. But as we may not know what this represents, could you say what you want the first rows to be in the dataframe. I could not guess what are the fields and the separators.

Comment: "003      ""|""   ""|""         ""|""7105926         FAN MILK TEMA - GHANA 5105494/5404," 540 5105495/5408        sample data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your initial file is not in a correct csv format. Long story short, the only reasonable thing to do is to have the producer of that horror fix the format. If it is not possible, it is possible to use the csv module to try to fix it by decoding once each row and outputting the first and only field:

```
import csv

with open("commaSeperated.csv") as fdin, open("fixed.csv", newline="\r\n") as fdout:
    rd = csv.reader(fdin, delimiter='|', quotechar='"')
    for row in rd:
        print(row[0], file=fdout)
```

Once this is done, you could try to load it into a pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.read_csv("fixed.csv", sep=r"\|")
```

Comment: so i tried this, but am getting 'File Not Found: [errno 2] no such file or directory : "fixed.csv" '

Comment: @EmmanuelOseiMensah: the previous code should have created it.